# How to have a "border" around a image placed in a scrollviewer

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, scrollviewer

I'm creating a windows store app and on a page I have a large image placed inside a ScrollViewer to enable the user to use touch gestures to pan and zoom around in the image. So far, so good, except one thing. I would like to tweak it so there is a "buffer" for panning so that the user can "overpan" to the extent that **at most** half of the image is off the screen, regardless of the ZoomFactor - or how much the user has zoomed in or out.

My question is, how would I go about implementing this? One person suggested to pad the image top,left, bottom, right with transparent uielements, but I don't think that statically-sized inserted uielements will be able to achieve the "at most half of the image off the screen" requirement.

Any ideas? Thank you for your help in advance.

EDIT:
Added code per request

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ImageViewer" Background="White" ZoomMode="Enabled" 
                  IsVerticalRailEnabled="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="False" 
                  VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                  MinZoomFactor=".22" MaxZoomFactor="2"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
            <Image x:Name="map" Source="map.png" ImageOpened="map_Loaded_1"/>

    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And this is the code behind for an event

```
    const float _defaultZoomFactor = 0.23F;
    private void map_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageViewer.ZoomToFactor(_defaultZoomFactor);
    }
```

Comment: well I did try the above mentioned, tried making a canvas larger than the image and putting both in the scrollviewer. I also tried following the sample from Microsoft to implement ManipulationMode but it got too complex

Comment: Can you add the code that you have thus far or the sample from Microsoft?

Comment: Can you not just give it a large `Margin` ?

Comment: I just tried adding a margin and it starts to mess with the pinch zoom, it starts doing funky things when an edge of the image is visible on the screen like translating image toward exposed side when fingers are raised

Comment: interesting, maybe embed it in a `Border` with padding set? I wouldn't have expected it so difficult :/

Answer (score 0):

You could add a dinamic margin to image UI element, that's calculated from the image size on the `Loaded` event, which is different from `ImageOpened`.

Xaml side:

```
<Image x:Name="map" Source="map.png" ImageOpened="map_Loaded_1" Loaded="OnImageElementLoaded"/>
```

And code side (mockup):

```
private void OnImageUILoaded( object sender , RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //Get image size
  //Calculate margin size
  //Set (Image)sender's new margin
}
```